# Jsonify Return is returning empty

Tags: python, json, flask

I have an issue that is driving me crazy. I have a function that I run in an API I am building in Flask. I am returning JSON values depending on certain things happening. I am going to just show you four lines of code because the rest shouldn't really matter here:

```
print 'example' not in json_string
return jsonify({'error': 'Error entering user.'})

if 'example' not in json_string:
    return jsonify({'error': 'Error entering user.'})
```

So basically I run this the first time and it prints `True` returns:

```
{'error': 'Error entering user.'}
```

And then I comment that first return out and it validates the if statement and returns:

```
{}
```

What in the world is going on here? I've copied the exact same line but it will not return a value after the IF statement. It does return an empty set but returns nothing in it.

Makes no sense to me. Any ideas? Thanks!

UPDATE

In the second instance, if I print it before returning it I get `<Response 55 bytes [200 OK]>` so there is something there. Why is it not getting returned?

Comment: Are those lines all part of the same function?

Comment: Yes they are in the same function. For more context, it's within a try function and I've realized that it is getting to the 'finally' part of the function now. I don't understand why it would be getting there though because it prints out anything in that if statement. I'll expand upon the question now with some more details now that I'm getting more here...

Comment: Ah, I'm being stupid. The return that I'm passing is actually returning the try function, not the overall function. I'll expand upon my question in case anyone else has the same problem.

Comment: Don't forget that a `finally` is always executed whether or not an exception is raised... so if that portion of it is falling off the end/doing a return... that'll potentially also cause confusion...

Comment: Thanks, yeah that makes sense. I was making some mistakes with how a try/except/finally function works so I'll detail it here. I'm sure others have had the same problem and I couldn't find anything on here that could help.

Comment: Don't use dict style input,  like this : `jsonify(error = 'Error entering user.',user='Invalid')`

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the response - `<Response 55 bytes [200 OK]>` when printing because jsonify returns a response object with headers ideally meant for broswers and API calls.

If you need to see or use the payload/data in your script, use json.dumps or call the data attribute on the response object. E.g.

```
return jsonify({'error': 'Error entering user.'}).data
```